# Snap SVG rotate doesn't work same in chrome and firefox

Tags: svg, cross-browser, snap.svg

I am working with SVG elements using snapSVG and I noticed that transformation in chrome and firefox doesn't work as it should. The code perfectly works with chrome but not with firefox.

I am trying to rotate an image with a overlaying mask for which the image is rotated in some degree clockwise for which the mask rotates some degrees in counter clockwise. The following generates a transformation matrix that works perfectly in Chrome but not in firefox.

```
 var imageCenterX = imageObj.posx+imageObj.width/2;
  var imageCenterY = imageObj.posy+imageObj.height/2;
  var transformString = "r"+imageObj.rotate+","+imageCenterX+","+imageCenterY;
  var transformStringMask = "r-"+imageObj.rotate+","+imageCenterX+","+imageCenterY;

  image.transform(transformString);
  mask.transform(transformStringMask);
```

**In chrome:**

Image html:

```
<image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="imgSrc.jpeg" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="211" y="74.191" width="480" height="480" mask="url('#Si9xqb7h9ys')" id="image1" transform="matrix(0.7071,-0.7071,0.7071,0.7071,-90.0717,410.9296)"></image>
```

Mask html:

```
<mask id="Si9xqb7h9ys"><g transform="matrix(0.7071,0.7071,-0.7071,0.7071,354.2614,-226.8807)"><rect x="211" y="74.191" width="298" height="480" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000"></rect></g></mask>
```

**In firefox:**

Image html:

```
<image transform="matrix(0.7071,0.7071,-0.7071,0.7071,414.2614,-251.7336)" id="image1" mask="url('#Si9xrhyed2z')" style="" height="600" width="600" y="74.191" x="211" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="imgSrc.jpeg"></image>
```

Mask html:

```
<mask id="Si9xqofuf2z"><g><rect stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff" style="" height="480" width="298" y="74.191" x="211"></rect></g></mask>
```

What I saw was that the mask object doesn't even get a transform attribute.

Why is this happening and is there any work around for this issue?

Comment: Can you create a runnable testcase e.g. as a jsfiddle?

Comment: As Robert says, I think you need to put up a fiddle. I'm not even sure transforms are applicable to masks, maybe Robert may know more on that ?

Comment: You can't have a transform on the `<mask>` itself but you can transform the mask contents which is what appears to be happening here.

Comment: The reason this is happening is in Firefox image transform does not work in SVG. I don't know why; I hope this question gets attention. Do you think you could reduce your example to the simplest `<image transform="matrix(1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0, 0)" xlink:href="imgSrc.jpeg"></image>` or something and post a fiddle?